# Pretty faces does not work in spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, friendly-url, prettyfaces

i have a problem with Pretty Faces... I'm trying mapping the urls in the file "pretty-config.xml" but the file doesn't read. When i try to access an url the console says that "No mapping for GET "

[error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipNoi.png)

[pretty-config.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLIBA.png)

[my browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBXvn.png)

I tried add a filter in my SpringBootAplication but without success (error 500)

Comment: Please include code/configuration as code blocks not links to off-site resources. Also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your question.